# html: perform other actions after following a href link

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

*Background*

Here's what I want to happen:

A user is on one page1.html ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urfatty/3b3cvtgm/)).
When they click on one of the `<a href...>` links, I want to navigate to page2.html ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urfatty/27zhf8g3/)) and simulate the user entering the number into the textbox and clicking on the button.

Example: On page1.html, user clicks on `display 2`. Then we will navigate to page2.html and get an alert of `2` (as if user had entered `2` and clicked the button).

---

*Question*

How do I do this?

1. Is there a way to make a C# method with a specific URL to navigate to, such as `page2.html/searchfor/2`?
2. Or is there some way in JavaScript to manually go about doing other things *after* navigating to `<a href="page2.html">`?

---

*Things I've tried*

- Using a `<span>` with an `onclick` function, but then it's not a true link like `<a href>` where I can middle click to open in new tab and right click to follow link
- Wrapping my first attempt in `<a href>` tags, like `<span><a href="page2.html">Display 2</a></span>`. This still doesn't solve the problem of performing extra actions after navigation.

---

*Note*

I am building this webpage using Entity Framework, ASP.NET MVC, and C#.
I have simplified the problem for discussion purposes, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Just make a link to an MVC action that takes parameters in the path or querystring.

Comment: So I could make a C# function that takes in a parameter, then call that function from html using something like `<a href=someRoot/myFunction/myParameter>`. But then how would I do page navigation and clicking the button from C#?

Comment: You don't; you write server-side code that does whatever you want, then serves the page.  You need to learn about HTTP and ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Your claiming to be using MVC but referring to static files such as `page1.html`. Perhaps you should begin with [Learn About ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the page2.html document's onload() function. You can pass parameters through the URL, then take that data and perform "other actions" as soon as the document is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing.